# Right way to ask a question

Tags: discussion, support

I have asked a couple of questions on the `magento.stackexchange.com` site since I started developing a few custom modules for my site. Unfortunately, there haven't been many answers though, even though I strongly believe those questions are valid and somewhat well written (at least good enough to understand what I mean).
I have taken care that they're

- not too long
- always just about one question
- well formatted
- as specific as possible
- whatever else I forgot.

Maybe someone would be kind enough to look at my profile (there are only 7 questions or so) and give me a hint. Are they too complicated? Am I doing something wrong? Is this happening by accident?

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions look pretty good. I'm a *little* busy these days with the M2 beta, but I'll look when I can. In the meantime I did try to [give your questions a little more exposure](https://twitter.com/benmarks/status/545212218049310720).

Comment: wow, thanks :) glad my issues aren't unheard because my questions are crap or something